# struggling with if else college assignment. Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to change month_days using the user input from month_num. if month_num is 1 I want it to change month_days to 31. What do I have wrong here? currently the program returns: 'you messed up.
That month is January and it has 30 days'

```
month_num =(int(input('Enter month number: ')))
if month_num == 1:
    month_num = 'January'

else:
   print('Go count the months for me and come back.')

month_days = ('30')
if month_num == 1:
    month_days = ('31')
else:
    print('you messed up.')

print('That month is', month_num, 'and it has', month_days, 'days')
```

Comment: Think about what `month_num` is after `month_num = 'January'` runs. Can it be equal to 1 in the check `if month_num == 1:`?

Comment: Ahh if month_num == 'January'

Comment: Yes. I would say that `if month_num == 1: month_num = 'January'` is the odd part though. You have `month_num` as a number initially (which makes sense), but then overwrite the "month **number**" variable with a **string name** of a month. To me, that doesn't make any sense, and may have been what led to your confusion. I'd create a new variable called `month_name` or something, assign the name to that, then you have both pieces of data available if need-be.

Answer (score 0):

the 'month_num' in your code after the first if block changes to 'January'.
You'd better use another name for 'January' or change this condition `if month_num == 1:` to `if month_num == 'January':`.

```
month_num =(int(input('Enter month number: ')))
if month_num == 1:
    month = 'January'

else:
   print('Go count the months for me and come back.')

month_days = ('30')
if month_num == 1:
    month_days = ('31')
else:
    print('you messed up.')

print('That month is', month, 'and it has', month_days, 'days')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when programming, you have to be *very* specific, down to every single character. `1`, `'1'`, `'(1)'` are all VERY different things in Python. Secondly, you need to understand types and be aware that when you assign a number to a variable then later assign a string to the same variable, you have just changed the type of the variable. This usually isn't a good thing to do. Here's modified code that works:

```
month_num = (int(input('Enter month number: ')))
if month_num == 1:
    month_str = 'January'

else:
   print('Go count the months for me and come back.')

month_days = 30
if month_num == 1:
    month_days = 31
else:
    print('you messed up.')

print('That month is {} and it has {} days'.format(month_str, month_days))
```

As you can see, I've changed a few things.